How can i use google api key in the custom GeoThreeExtension in autodesk forge viewer
hree = THREE;
// Ensure 'three' is defined if needed: three = THREE;

class GeoThreeExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
      super(viewer, options);
      this.viewer = viewer;
    }
  
    load() {
      var provider = new Geo.DebugProvider();
      var DEV_BING_API_KEY =
        "AuViYD_FXGfc3dxc0pNa8ZEJxyZyPq1lwOLPCOydV3f0tlEVH-HKMgxZ9ilcRj-T";
      var provider = new Geo.BingMapsProvider(
        DEV_BING_API_KEY,
        Geo.BingMapsProvider.ROAD
      );
  
      

      var map = new Geo.MapView(Geo.MapView.PLANAR, provider);
      map.position.set(14900, -27300, -45);
      this.viewer.overlays.addScene("map");
      this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(map, "map");
      map.updateMatrixWorld(false);
  
      this.viewer.autocam.shotParams.destinationPercent = 3;
      this.viewer.autocam.shotParams.duration = 3;
      var cam = this.viewer.getCamera();
  
      var coords = Geo.UnitsUtils.datumsToSpherical(40.940119, -8.535589);
      cam.target.set(coords.x, 0, -coords.y);
      cam.position.set(0, 1000, 0);
  
      this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, () => {
        this.viewer.autocam.toPerspective();
        map.lod.updateLOD(
          map,
          cam,
          this.viewer.impl.glrenderer(),
          this.viewer.overlays.impl.overlayScenes.map.scene,
          this.viewer.impl
        );
      });
      return true;
    }
  
    unload() {
      return true;
    }
  }
  
  Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
    "GeoThreeExtension",
    GeoThreeExtension
  );

This is the custom GeoThreeExtension so instead of  DEV_BING_API_KEY ,I have google api key .
so how can i use that in this extension.
I have get this code from the git resource https://github.com/wallabyway/geo-three-ext.
when i  used the below GOOGLE_MAPS_API_  instead of  DEV_BING_API_KEY
 var GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY = "YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY";
    var provider = new Geo.GoogleMapsProvider(GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY);

iam getting errors.
I want to use google api key in the custom GeoThreeExtension .
how can i use that ,Please help me .
iam using autodesk forge viewer
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/7.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

Thanks in advance

Unfortunately, it's not supported in my sample.  I only copied over the Bing map part of the GeoThree code, into my sample custom extension.
However, if you are keen, you could copy back the missing Google maps code section, from GeoThree extension, back into this custom extension.  Once it's back in there, you could add your Google API key.
Does your key work with the original geoThree demo?
